# Инкрементный вывод результатов деления в цикле C++

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать инкрементный вывод результатов деления в цикле. 
Например 44:11=4 и нужно чтобы к делимому и делителю каждый раз прибавлялась 1.
Ну то есть следующее будет 45:12=3.75 и так далее.
Так 100 раз проделать надо к примеру) Напишите как это делается пожалуйста)

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается сделать? (только не говорите, что вообще всё)

Comment: Просто тупанул)

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/R6oL2l

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct magic { int a, b; };
inline magic & operator ++ (magic &m) { return ++m.a, ++m.b, m; }
inline double operator * (const magic &m) { return (double)m.a / m.b; }
inline bool operator != (const magic &l, const magic &r) { return l.a!=r.a || l.b!=r.b; }

auto t = for_each(magic {44, 11}, magic {144, 111}, [](double x) { cout << x << '\n'; });

int main() {}
```

---

http://ideone.com/sjYORy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace std
{
struct magic { int a, b; };
inline magic & operator ++ (magic &m) { return ++m.a, ++m.b, m; }
inline double operator * (const magic &m) { return (double)m.a / m.b; }

template <> struct iterator_traits<magic> : iterator_traits<istream_iterator<double>> {};

int z = (copy_n(magic {44, 11}, 100, ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n")), 0);
}

int main() {}
```

Comment: Мой компилятор ругается на этот код...

Comment: @AruAkice, нужен более современный компилятор :)

Comment: Для совсем новых версий GCC нужно, судя по всеу, `#include <ext/algorithm>` + `__gnu_cxx::copy_n`.

Comment: Я не могу понять, как добавить сюда(в этот код) количество чисел после запятой, а то 1.11111 я хочу сделать например 9 знаков..

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
for(int q = 44, d = 11; q < 144; ++q, ++d)
    cout << q << "/" << d << "= " << double(q)/d << endl;
```